# Getting "Specify which project file to use..." error when ef scaffolding

Tags: mysql, .net, entity-framework-core, ef-database-first, asp.net-core-scaffolding

When I tried to execute scaffold command in PMC I am getting the following error :

```
    dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "server=127.0.0.1:3308;uid=root;pwd=root;database=newtest_db" MySql.EntityFrameworkCore -o MySQLDataOperations -f

dotnet : Specify which project file to use because this 'D:\Projects\DotNet5_Docker' contains more than one project file.
At line:1 char:1
 dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "server=127.0.0.1:3308;uid=root;pwd=root 
     CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Specify which p...e project file.:String) [], RemoteException
     FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Also executed by adding -p project name -s project name.
still repeating the same error.

Since this folder contains more than one projects and solution I have created a new project and tried the same then the error became below mentioned:

```
dotnet : Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
At line:1 char:1
 dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "server=127.0.0.1:3308;uid=root;pwd=root ...
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Could not execu... was not found.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
Possible reasons for this include:
   You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
   You intended to execute a .NET program, but dotnet-ef does not exist.
   You intended to run a 
global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
```

I am using Visual Studio 2019. Tried the same in Powershell also. My intention is to implement data base first approach from an already existing MySQL data base using MySQL.Data.EntityframeworkCore

[PMC Error for first project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJ3cr.jpg)

[PMC Error for another project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nb8N5.jpg)